# What is Sri Chaitanya's Shiksastakam?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya

Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu left only 8 verses of his instruction in his writing known as Shiksastakam. What are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Sri Chaitanya's Shiksastakam with their English translations taken from Life and Precepts of Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu by Srila Bhaktivinoda Thakur.

First:

> cheto-darpana-marjanam bhava-mahadavagni-nirvapanam
>   sreya-kairava-chandrika-vitaranam vidhyavadhu-jivanam
>   anandambudhi-vardhanam prati-padam purnamritasvadanam
>   sarvatma-snapanam param vijayate sri-krishna-sankirtanam
>
> May the chanting of the Holy Name of Sri Krishna be glorified, which
>   (i) sweeps of all the dirts from the mirrors of our hearts, (ii}
>   extinguishes the great forest fire of suffering from the cycle of
>   births and deaths. (iii) sheds moonlight upon the lily of eternal
>   Good. (iv) is the very Life of bride of Real Learning, (v) swells the
>   Ocean of Ecstatic Bliss, (vi) gives the full taste of Pure Nectar at
>   every utterance of the Holy Name and ( vii ) bathes i.e. purifies and
>   refreshes the whole self including body mind and soul in Divine Bliss.
>   (1)

Second:

> namnam akari bahudha nija-sarva-shaktis tatrarpita niyamitah smarane
>   na kalah etadrishi tava kripa bhagavan mamapi durdaivam idrisam
>   ihajani nanuragah
>
> O Almighty Supreme Lord , Thou hast out of thy Infinite Mercy, given
>   to the world a multiplicity of Thy Names, endowed Each of the Names
>   with all Thy Potencies and made no restrictions as to the time, place
>   etc., of their recitations and remembrance. But alas! such is my luck
>   that I have no love for chanting thy names (2)

Third

> trinad api sunicena taror api sahisnuna amanina manadena kirtaniya
>   sada harih
>
> He, who is humbler than a blade of grass, is more forbearing than a
>   tree and honors others, yet without any desire of honoring himself, is
>   ever worthy of chanting the Holy Name. (3)

Fourth:

> na dhanam na janam na sundarim kavitam va jagadisha kamaye mama
>   janmani janmanisvare bhavatad bhaktir ahaituki tvaya
>
> No riches, no friends or relatives, no beautiful muses do I pray Thee
>   for, but may my heart ever cling to Thee, 0 Supreme Lord, out of
>   selfless devotion and love, whenever and wherever I may he born.(4)

Fifth:

> ayi nanda-tanuja kinkaram patitam mam vishame bhavambudhau kripaya
>   tava pada-pankajasthita- dhuli-sadrisham, vichintaya
>
> 0 Son of Nanda! graciously count me Thy servant, as a particle of dust
>   of Thy Lotus Feet, fallen as I am in the terrible ocean of this world.
>   (5)

Sixth:

> nayanam galad asru-dharaya vadanam gadgada-ruddhaya gira pulakair
>   nicitam vapuh kada tava nama-grhane bhavisyate
>
> "When will my eyes, 0 Lord, at the chanting of Thy Name, be filled
>   with flowing tears, my voice become choked and the hair of my body
>   stand up in ecstasy?(6)

Seventh:

> yugayitam nimeshena chakshusha pravrishayitam sunyayitam jagat sarvam
>   govinda-virahena me
>
> The Separation from my Beloved Govinda makes an instant, i.e., the
>   twinkling of an eye, seem to me to be an aeon, my eyes are turned into
>   the rainy season itself and the whole world appears to me a void. (7)

Eigth:

> ashlisya va pada-ratam pinastu mam adarshanan marma-hatam karotu va
>   yatha tatha va vidadhatu lampado mat-prana-nathas tu sa eva naparah
>
> Whether Krishna, my Beloved, hugs me in His sweet embrace or tramples
>   me under His Feet, or torments me by keeping Himself away from me,
>   gratifying His Amours in whatever manner He likes. He and none else is
>   the Lord of my life. (8)

Comment: Questioning and Answering simultaneously !! Is this encouraged on HiSE? Is this a preaching platform? I can not downvote though, as these are words of Sri Bhagavan!

Comment: @commonman "Questioning and Answering simultaneously !! Is this encouraged on HiSE?" Yes. It is allowed

Comment: May be allowed, but I do not think is encouraged! One can study about the topic and answer later, but asking and answering simultaneously does not look good!